# rsqlite create index

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have been trying to use the RSQLite (with DBI) to create a database in R but i have millions of rows and i would like to create an index to speed up the queries. Unfortunately i haven't been able to find a way to do this with the library. Is there a way or another library that can be used to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly with RSQLite

```
library(RSQLite)
...
dbExecute(con, 'CREATE INDEX idx_adl ON adltable(x)')
```